# Live interaction between Frontend and backend

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, thymeleaf

I'm busy making a controller website where I switch relays on and off.
My switching has a schedule on so it can be activated without human interaction.
my question is how can I do a live update on my HTML frontend, if the scheduler activates a switch, to show the user the switch is active without needing to refresh the page?

I have a basic spring boot application with tomcat angularjs and thymeleaf

Comment: use push or pull request.

Comment: @LaurentB but wouldnt eat resources doing constant requests?

Comment: Well at some point you got to use some resource. Be it a permanent connection for server push or frequent updates (at an interval of your choice) for pull request.

Comment: If you do not want the client to call the server, you must use push notifications or sockets to communicate from server to client.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using SSE (Server-SentEvents) described for [example on baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events).

```
@GetMapping(path = "/stream-flux", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> streamFlux() {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
      .map(sequence -> "Flux - " + LocalTime.now().toString());
}
```

PS: There is also websocket technology suitable for this need, but it does not support HTTP 2 and SSE is more suitable for such one way update.